# How to compare the value of two selects in Javascript with dynamic content using javascript

Tags: javascript

I currently have these two conditions that must be met for a modal to display on screen:

```
if($("#id_form-0-calculated").val() === $("#id_form-0-modified").val()) {
  if($("#id_form-0-calculated").val() === $("#id_form-0-modified").val()) {
    $("#Modal").modal();
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for the first element (`N = 0`), the problem is that the web page I am editing can have N elements with the following pattern:

`id_form-N-calculated` / `id_form-N-modified`

How could I make the if statements dynamic and work for all existing N values instead of just one static value?

Comment: Please show your whole code to better understand what you want.

Comment: Just I have 4 selects, in order to display a modal the two if conditions must be met.

The thing is, for the same page I have N elements, each element has also that 4 selects.

Comment: If you provide your HTML, people may have a better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks but actually I've got the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how will you do this, but I regularly use the following:

```
var N = 0;

if($("#id_form-"+N+"-calculated_ad_pathogenicity").val() === $("#id_form-"+N+"-modified_ad_pathogenicity").val()) {
   if($("#id_form-"+N+"-calculated_ar_pathogenicity").val() === $("#id_form-"+N+"-modified_ar_pathogenicity").val()) {
      $("#Modal").modal();
   }
}
```

Most of the time, N is used in either loops or functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function something like

```
function check(n){
    if($("#id_form-" + n + "-calculated_ad_pathogenicity").val() === $("#id_form-" + n + "-modified_ad_pathogenicity").val()) {
      if($("#id_form-" + n + "-calculated_ar_pathogenicity").val() === $("#id_form-" + n + "-modified_ar_pathogenicity").val()) {
        $("#Modal").modal();
      }
    }
}
```

Adding it to the checking flow. For example

```
const n = 4;

for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
     check(i);
}
```